# Why do some variables show up as "undefined" when using the Node.js debugger? This does not happen when running the program normally

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, dotenv

I ran into some issues with my program, so I started to learn how to use the node.js debugger. I have the following `index.js`:

```
import app from "./server.js"   // imports root
import mongodb from "mongodb"   // helps conect to mongodb
import dotenv from "dotenv"     // helps configure environment variables automatically
import DailyDAO from "./dao/dailyDAO.js"    // DAO file contains CRUD material

// configures dotenv
dotenv.config()       // New breakpoint here
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient 

// This is the port where our local server will listen to the MongoDB Atlas server
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const url = process.env.SOLAR_DB_URI    

// Connects local VSC server to the MongoDB Atlas server
MongoClient.connect(
    url,
    {
        maxPoolSize: 50,
        waitQueueTimeoutMS: 2500
    }
)
.catch(err => { // If there is an error, this is executed
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
})
.then(async client => { 
    await DailyDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Connected to: ' + url)
        console.log('listening on port: ' + port)
    })
})
```

When running this through the debugger with no breakpoints, I receive the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')

When I stop at the breakpoint, I can see that `port` and `url` are both undefined. When I run the program normally, both variables have the expected values.

These variables are defined in a separate file `.env`. So I'm assuming that when running this file through the debugger, it is not accessing `.env` properly. Why does the debugger do this, and how do I make `index.js` access the values in `.env` while in the debugger?

Edit: This is what my `.env` file looks like

```
SOLAR_DB_URI=mongodb+srv://admin:fakepassword@solarpanel-db.sbqf66p.mongodb.net/daily_production?retryWrites=true&w=majority
PORT=5000
SOLAR_NS=daily_production
```

Edit: I am using a node.js debugger that comes built into VSC. To start the debugger, I select the desired file and select the run and e (in this case `index.js`) from my explorer and then select the "Run and Debug" button.

Edit: Ok so I made a different breakpoint at `dotenv.config()`. It turns out that this function is incorrectly resolving the path of my cwd.

Edit: Alright so, inside `dotenv.config()` looks like this:

```
function config(options) {
  // Irrelevant code  

  let dotenvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env');  // There is a problem here

  // Irrelevant code
}
```

The directory where `index.js` and `.env` are located is `%PATH%\solarmonitor\backend\`, but when I run the debugger it's resolving to just `%PATH%\solarmonitor\` instead.

Edit: These are my debugger's configurations from `launch.json`, as requested by @Bergi:

```
{
    /?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\backend\\index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What debugger are you using and how are you starting it?  And how exactly are the environment variables `PORT` and `SOLAR_DB_URI` getting configured.  Presumably, they are just not configured in the environment that you're using when you run the debugger.

Comment: Dotenv is path-dependent iirc. So make sure your debugger starts the `node` process in the same working directory as your normal execution.

Comment: @Bergi `node` starts in the same directory as the selected file. The `index.js` and `.env` are in the same directory, so they should be able to interact normally no?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have just added that information as an edit.

Comment: "*`node` starts in the same directory as the selected file*" - are you sure there? Could you post your *launch.json* (at least the part with the debugging configuration), please?

Comment: @Bergi just posted it. The program launches from `\backend\index.js` which is the expected directory. Also, I think that the `dotenv.config()` might be the problem. Inside the function, the path to the cwd is resolving incorrectly. I added some edits with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically figured out what the problem is already - your program is started with in wrong working directory. VS Code is basically running `node backend\index.js` in your workspace folder, which is the default working directory for any launch configuration.

You can change this setting using the [`cwd` launch configuration attribute](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes):

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\backend",
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\backend\\index.js"
}
```

For your particular problem, you could also [configure VS Code to provide the environment variables from your `.env` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_load-environment-variables-from-external-file), in which case you wouldn't need `dotenv`.

Comment: Alright! Now I can debug in peace. But you know, I'm still confused. If the debugger knows the absolute path of the program already, as shown in the `program` attribute, why do I need to specify the `cwd`?

Comment: NEVERMIND! I just read the documentation for `cwd`. It always defaults to the "workingFolder` unless otherwise specified. I'm good. I wish I could up-vote, but I don't have enough reputation yet.